# How i can update a managed metadata column with multiple values using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I have the following code inside my remote event reciever, to create a new folder, and then populate the folder managed metadata fields with the current item (item that was added) values:-

```
ListItem listItem = context.Web.GetList(webrelativeurl +  "/"+i2["TemplateListUrl"]).AddItem(listItemCreationInformation);

listItem["FolderType"] = currentitem["FolderType"];
listItem["CorpType"] = currentitem["CorpType"];
```

now the `FodlerType` on both the current item and the listitem is a managed metadata column which allow single value only, while the `CorpType` allow multiple values. my above code will assign a value for the `FolderType` , but will raise this error when updating the CorpType:-

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestException
>   HResult=0x80131500   Message=The object is not associated with an
>   object identity or the object identity is invalid.   Source=   StackTrace:

any advice?

Comment: Check [this](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.com/2011/08/sharepoint-2010-code-tips-setting.html). Maybe it will help you.

Comment: @GaneshSanap thanks for the link,but it is not clear how to achieve this

Comment: hi, I think I posted an answer for the same question on Overflow :). Please check if it was of any help :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60266593/update-a-managed-metadata-column-with-multiple-values-using-csom/60270486#60270486

Answer (score 2):

You need to get a [`TaxonomyFieldValueCollection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj166171%28v%3Doffice.15%29) use the [`SetFieldValueByValueCollection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj165507(v=office.15)) of the [`TaxonomyField`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj165648(v=office.15)) object.

```
var field = item.ParentList.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("CorpType");
var corpTypeTaxField = context.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(field);
context.Load(item,i=>i[TaxKeywordFieldName]);

corpTypeTaxField.SetFieldValueByValueCollection(listItem, (TaxonomyFieldValueCollection) currentitem["CorpType"]);
```

Note, this gets a lot messier if you have terms that you need to look up to construct a `TaxonomyFieldValueCollection` from scratch -- copying it from another item is definitely easier.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i can not find a method named "GetFieldValueByValueCollection".. there is a method named "GetFieldValueAsTaxonomyFieldValueCollection"

Comment: i replaced `GetFieldValueByValueCollection` with `GetFieldValueAsTaxonomyFieldValueCollection`.. but i will get this error `The given guid does not exist in the term store'`.. any idea?

Comment: Is your source item from a different site than your destination item?

Comment: the same site and the same list

Comment: Can you debug and see what the value of `currentitem["CorpType"].ToString()` is?  Is it possible that the current item is referencing a term that has been deleted?

Comment: i define the following `var test= currentitem["CorpType"].ToString();` and the value for the `test` will be `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection`

Comment: Okay, looks like I may have over-complicated things, I edited my answer to just pass the currentItem's value directly to the `set` function.

Comment: thanks for the update , but i will get this error now `: 'The object is not associated with an object identity or the object identity is invalid` on `corpTypeTaxField.SetFieldValueByValueCollection(listItem, (TaxonomyFieldValueCollection) currentitem["CorpType"]);    `

Comment: What happens it you call `listItem.update()` and `contect.ExecuteQuery()` **before** setting the TaxonomyFieldValueCollection?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the code as below.

```
List list = context.Web.GetList(webrelativeurl + "/" + i2["TemplateListUrl"]);

Field field = list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("CorpType");
context.Load(field);
context.ExecuteQuery();

TaxonomyField txField = context.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(field);
TaxonomyFieldValueCollection termValues = null;
string termValueString = string.Empty;
termValues = currentitem["CorpType"] as TaxonomyFieldValueCollection;
foreach (TaxonomyFieldValue tv in termValues)
{
    termValueString += tv.WssId + ";#" + tv.Label + "|" + tv.TermGuid + ";#";
}
termValueString= termValueString.Remove(termValueString.Length - 2);
termValues = new TaxonomyFieldValueCollection(context, termValueString, txField);

ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
ListItem listItem = list.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
listItem["FolderType"] = currentitem["FolderType"];
txField.SetFieldValueByValueCollection(listItem, termValues);
listItem.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```